# Reading float data from SerialPort in Node.js

Tags: node.js, serial-port

I am sending measurement data from arduino via serialport

```
float mA, Volt = 0.0f;
UART_writeFloat(Volt);
UART_writeFloat(mA);

void UART_writeFloat (float value)
  {
     const byte * p = (const byte*) &value;
     for (byte i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          Serial.write(*p++);
  }
```

And accept in the server on Ubuntu with NodeJS.
I don't know anything about NodeJS, but the code from the example of working with the serialport receives only raw data into the buffer.

```
var buffer = '';
var Voltage = 0.0;
var Current = 0.0;
port.on('data', function(buffer) {
        console.log(buffer);
    });
```

and so I get

```
<Buffer 6f 83 60 40 c1 14 74 c1>
```

help get my sent data into two float variables Voltage and Current.

Answer (score 0):

Found !!!

```
var vVolt = new blynk.VirtualPin(25);
var vIrms = new blynk.VirtualPin(26);
var vPWR = new blynk.VirtualPin(27);

    port.on('data', function(chunk) {

       Voltage = chunk.readFloatLE(0);
       Current = chunk.readFloatLE(4);
       Power   = chunk.readFloatLE(8);

        vVolt.write(Voltage);
        vIrms.write(Current);
        vPWR.write(Power);
    });
```